# Add context to IntelliJ html import assist

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I'm coding some HTML in IntelliJ as part of a Java web app.  Inside `index.html` I'll use relative links like

```
<script src="/lft/ng-app/lft.js"></script>
```

where `lft` is the servlet context and the file structure looks like

```
/index.html
/ng-app
    /lft.js
```

When I use relative links like the script import example IntelliJ can't resolve the link since it doesn't know about the context and the result is no code completion.

How can I tell the IDE about my context and get code completion back?